# jquery knob responsive resize doesn't work in resizable bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-knob

I am trying to have a jQuery knob widget within a bootstrap panel to be resized automatically
when panel itself gets resized (thanks to jQuery UI resizable).

*HTML:*

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-info dashboard_panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">HELLO 2</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <input type="text" class="dial" id="knob1" data-min="-50" data-width="100%" data-height="50%" data-max="50"></input>
                <button class="button button-default">Just a button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*JS:*

```
$(".dashboard_panel").resizable();
$(".dial").knob();
```

*CSS:*

```
.dashboard_panel {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Here is the link to the code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mguijarr/8jLkjzsc/5/)

I am expecting initial height of the knob widget to be 100 pixels height (50% of 200 pixels minimum height of the parent element), which is not the case. Then I am expecting the
height to always be 50% of the size, but it doesn't work neither.

Can someone help me, please ? :)

Comment: Are you sure your jsFiddle is the correct one? I don't see any knobs.

Comment: I just updated the link; sorry. Now it should be ok.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I still can't see knobs :(. your knob() function is giving 'undefined is not a function'

Comment: Can't understand why... In 'external ressources' I added the link to the minified code for the jquery knob plugin: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/master/dist/jquery.knob.min.js , so the function should not be undefined it is working for me. I don't understand.

Comment: I was in Chrome on Mac, it does work in Firefox though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `height:100%` to your `.panel-body` class:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8jLkjzsc/12/)

```
.panel-body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Also, if you have `min-height` to your `.dashboard-panel` class the knob doesn't scale on load, not sure why. If you really don't need all dashboard panels to have the same height I'd consider removing it.

***Edit:** adding the same amount of `min-height` to the `.panel-body` class seems to have fixed it. I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: for some reason it can still get ugly when scaling it up, as the knob widget can get bigger than the container panel. I will try to investigate on this one...

Comment: Hmm.. not sure what you mean. This is what I'm getting when I increase the size: http://imgur.com/IE29GdY

Comment: oh yes, sorry I forgot to mention I set data-height for the knob widget to 100% (to occupy all panel space), then it gets weird on resizing

Comment: It comes from the fixed height of the .dashboard_panel when draggable does its magic on it. You can reset the height once you are done dragging, not sure if it that helps you. http://jsfiddle.net/8jLkjzsc/15/